# Injecting arbitrary data application wide instead of hierachically to child components

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

Simplified, I got a component hierarchy like this:

- RootComponent

  - MenubarComponent
  - RouterOutlet

    - (dynamic components based on route) Component X

In my menubar, there is a question mark icon that should point to a help page for the currently loaded component/page X. The URL that is used must be changed dynamically based on which component is currently active in the router outlet.

My first (and preferred) idea was to use an injection token that is injected into the menubar for each component or route in the router outlet. Of course this does not work with the hierarchical nature of Angular's dependency injection, because the injected value is not provided for the overall application but only for the component and it's child components.

I could define the URLs as value in the route's data field, which is not type safe and does not work for child routes. This solution seems to require additional type checking and extra work for child routes.

Another way could be to create a service with a special interface which is provided in root and which maps the type of the active component to a corresponding URL.

What's the "Angular solution" for this problem in general? How would I pass arbitrary and route specific data between components in this scenario? Is there another form of dependency injection?